# How can I protect multiple Next.js API routes in next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I build a simple API in Next.js and I use next-auth for authentication.

So far I have to use something like this in every API route:

```
  const session = await getSession({ req });
  if (session) {
    ... do something ...
  } else {
    ... send back a 401 status
  }
```

This seems to go against the DRY principle. Is there a clever way to apply protection to a number of routes in one place, such as Laravel route groups?

Comment: What about moving it to a helper/util/middleware function and call that in your API routes instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a middleware that gets the session otherwise returns 401.

See NextJS docs on [api middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/api-middlewares).
You can also check out [their example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes-middleware) in the github repo.

Comment: That's great but as far as I understand, I must refer to the middleware in each and every API route. In a pure express app I can define a middleware that covers many routes, in one go. For example, when using passport an unauthorized request does not even get passed to the route. Is something like this possible in NextJS?

Comment: I think you have to wrap every handler you need that middleware for in nextjs. Every api handler in NextJS is running in total isolation as a serverless function if I recall correctly. If you need more control take a read on [creating your own server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in NextJS. Might be able to add global middleware then.

Answer (score 3):

Make a middleware!

Disregard the typing if your not using TS

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next/types'
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/client'

export const protect = async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse,
  next: any
) => {
  const session = await getSession({ req })
  if (session) {
    console.log(session)
    next()
  } else {
    res.status(401)
    throw new Error('Not authorized')
  }
}
```